# Returning a .csv file error on prod, but not on test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

We have a system in ASP.NET MVC3 and we are running on IIS7.

My controller looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Display(string reportID)       
{
    string fullName = service.initiateGisTaxJurCsvGeneration();
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
    return File(fullName, "text/csv", fileName);
}
```

The service creates and saves a .csv file to the users local Windows temp directory.  The next two lines of code just return the file to the user in the browser so it can be downloaded.

The download of the file works fine on my local web server (the one build into Visual Studio).  We also have a test environment and a production environment.  They are on the same server and instance of IIS.  Test and prod are just different websites on the same instance of IIS.  Returning the file works perfectly fine from our test website, but the prod website is returning a code HTTP500.

This makes me think there has to be some setting somewhere in the IIS server that is different between the two different websites (prod and test).  I cannot find anything different between the two, but my knowledge of IIS is not that deep.  Is there anything you can think of that I may have missed that could possibly cause a problem such as this?

Comment: The test site is creating the temp file on my local temp directory, but the prod one is not

Comment: Check out permissions of user which is used for APP Pool identity